# Generic but pertinent and significant question

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I'm afraid to post this question, so I thought I would reach out and see what people's thoughts would be here, first. The problem is the question is not very specific -- it is an overarching inquiry into what is slowing down a Web application.

> While we have found many problems in the Java code and more than our fair share of database bottlenecks, we are trying to determine how much of a speedbump the front end is contributing. I wanted to see if I could get people's opinions on how to go about determining the fraction of slowness related to things like excessive HTTP requests and that sort of thing, as part of the overall equation with back end and database.

Is this a bad idea to post this on SO? I'm thinking yes, but where should I go, instead? (There simply is **no** better community than this!!)

Comment: `"I wanted to see if I could get people's opinions"` *Big* red flag there.  The exact text of the last close reason, `"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."`  Having said that, determining the % time a given HTTP requests spends on you server vs elsewhere isn't asking for an opinion; the answer is either correct or it's not. So just don't ask for an opinion.

Comment: Thank you. Your clarification on _opinion_ is worthy of consideration, and that is one reason I asked on here to see what types of things **would** be red flags. However, even though there is a potential concrete answer, I'd be asking people to speculate. When there are hundreds of thousands of lines of code, thousands of database tables and over 1500 front end pages, I couldn't possibly ask a specific enough question!

Comment: Then you have your answer.  If you're not capable of providing enough detail in the question for a factual, non-opinion based answer then it's not appropriate to post the question on SO.

Comment: <sigh> Yes, that is what I had thought. Any suggestions as to where one would go to ask wildly general questions to get some direction? (He asked, slyly, knowing it is another opinion-based question.) ;)

Comment: That's an offtopic question.  That said, going to chat is appropriate, either for info on the topic itself or just for a referral to another site.  Chat doesn't really have the strict standards of normal questions/answers.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can still post this question on SO, but change a few things first. Make it general enough to help any future user, and very importantly, show what have you tried.

> I am trying to determine how much time is spent in front-end vs back-end vs transit time. How mch of slowness is related to things like excessive HTTP requests and that sort of thing, as part of the overall equation with back end and database?
>
> I have looked at [some other SO question] and [other blog post] but [it is too general-case][did not help][etc].
>
> I am using [some Java framework] on [some web server] and mainly testing on [browser]. The Network tab of the inspector showed that transit time is 1234 ms. Where should I go from here?

Comment: Now I'm considering to downvote too, for the expletive. votes are taken very liberally on meta.

Comment: FWIW, I tried to upvote it, but I don't have enough reputation points. At its best, the SO/SE community is outstanding, at its worst it is plain evil and lacks true fairness. It really sucks, I feel like I'm walking on eggshells all the time!

Comment: Especially on meta. It's truly a lottery whether the post that you actually put effort into will go over well or poorly.

Comment: Yes, that is very true of meta. For what it is worth, you answered my question beautifully and it was quite helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Chill out, the downvotes just means they disagree with your suggestion, as in they think it's not possible to make the question *not* off-topic by rephrasing it.

Comment: That is a very narrow-minded approach.